# MS Office using wrong language dictionary

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, language

Just did a new install with Windows 8.1 64 bit.  Installed Office Professional Plus 2010.  When I use PPT or Outlook, (maybe others as well), I notice that a lot of words are indicated as mis-spelled when they are not (red wavy line under them).  For example, the phrase "Clear alignment ..." has both words underlined.  If I look at recommended words instead of "Clear", I get "Cledar, Clean, Ledar, Caler, Ceara".  I am in USA, and these are definitely not traditional English words, so my first thought is that the Language is wrong. In Outlook, if I go to File / Options / Language, both "Editing Language" and "Display and Help Language" show English(U.S.) .  It is the ONLY entry there.

OK.. check at the Windows Level...  From Control Panel / Language, only English (United States) is listed.   If I look at Language / Advanced Settings, all my options state (Use language list (recommended)   ).

I am at a loss where else to check.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What does it think the Proofing language is for that text (Highlight the text it thinks is wrong and then Review tab -> Language group -> Language button -> Set Proofing Language)?

Comment: It looks like some words are using the French Canadian proofing language, while other words are using English US.  Is there a way to set this at a document level?